# leds and motor on small diarama

Tags: power, led, batteries, resistors, battery-operated

Super new to doing electronics projects.  I have a project where I have attached 12 led lights in parallel to a small plastic tree.  The whole thing rotates on a motor.  I am using a 3v CR2450 battery to power the whole thing.  The lights dimming and eventually turning off completely within 10 mins of turning it on.  I would like it to run as long as possible and with ultimate brightness.  I am using 3mm yellow led lights and a geared motor.  How do I figure out if I am using the correct power source and if so what should I add to my circuit to make it work properly?

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.  I am not sure what and how to get these measurements.  The LEDs will like up singularly with a 3 volt battery and the motor will work singularly with a three volt battery.  How do I calculate/measure the power scource I would need for this?  Given the space I have to work with the only other battery that may fit is a 9v.  I am too new to make sense of your first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The [CR2450](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2450.pdf) is rated at 620 mAh typical, but only at an average drain of less than 0.4 mA (the equivalent of a 7.5 kΩ load). You are attempting to draw several orders of magnitude more current than that, so it isn't surprising that you get significantly less energy out of it.

You need to pick a power source that is more appropriate for your load. Start by deciding how much power you require (LEDs plus motor) and how long you expect it to run. This gives you the total energy needed. Then find a battery that meets BOTH the power and energy requirements.